# How to define collection of controls list in class library as property

Tags: c#, class, collections, properties

i'm using c# class library to create a custom control.
i have no problem with simple collection of type, this is an example how i use it:

```
namespace PersoComboBox
{

    public class ComboColDisplay
    {
        private string name;
        private int percentage;

        public string ColName
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }

        public int ColPercent
        {
            get { return this.percentage; }
            set { this.percentage = value; }
        }

        public ComboColDisplay()
        {
        }
    }

    public class PersoComboBox : ComboBox 
    {
        //Variables locales
        ErrorProvider EP = new ErrorProvider();
        //Collection property
        private List<ComboColDisplay> listColDisplay = new List<ComboColDisplay>();


        [Category("xControl properties")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<ComboColDisplay> PListColumnDisplay
        {
            get { return listColDisplay; }
            set { listColDisplay = value; Invalidate(); }
        }


        public PersoComboBox()
        {
        }

        private void refreshDrawMode()
        {
            if (listColDisplay.Count > 0) { this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable; }
            else { this.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to use collection of collection of type as a property !
how can i do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: A collection of collections is something like `List<List<SomeType>>`. Does that help? Not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes ! but i want to know the right way to use it in a class library project as a design time property.